# css panel width match max text width

Tags: html, css, panel

How do I make a whole floating panel width match maximum text width inside it?
It should be look like this:

[image: Sample]

pannel html is:

```css
.pannel{    
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
    border: #88F 4px solid;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgb(240,240,255);
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-size: 150%;
  }
.pannel>a>div
  {  
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: #AAF 1px solid;
    margin: 0 auto 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 9px;
    margin: 3px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="pannel">
  <a href="someref1">
    <div>
     <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg">
     <div>Some text</div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="someref2">
    <div>
     <img src="https://camo.mybb.com/e01de90be6012adc1b1701dba899491a9348ae79/687474703a2f2f7777772e6a71756572797363726970742e6e65742f696d616765732f53696d706c6573742d526573706f6e736976652d6a51756572792d496d6167652d4c69676874626f782d506c7567696e2d73696d706c652d6c69676874626f782e6a7067">
     <div>Some text2</div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="someref3">
    <div>
     <img src="http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg">
     <div>Text with a maximum width</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

As you can see, the panel size matched the maximum image size, but I want the images to fit to the width of the elements.

Comment: you want to set some text div whole content and image also show all content area?

Comment: Image's should be the same width as the maximum text size width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can do this with pure css is to have all the images have the same aspect ratio - if this is the case then you can use a trick with absolute positioning and padding-top.

In the example below, I have used images with a ratio of w:600px x h:400px (66.6666%)

```css
.pannel {
  display: inline-block;
}

.pannel > a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  padding-top:66.6666%; /* padding = height / width of image - 400px / 600px */
}

.image > img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0; 
  right:0;
  top:0; 
  max-width:100%;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="pannel">
  <a href="someref1">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg">
      </div>
      <div>Some text</div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="someref2">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/">
      </div>
      <div>Some text2</div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="someref3">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg"> </div>
      <div>Text with a maximum width</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

If you are unable to have all the images have the same aspect ratio, then this is not possible with pure css and you would need a little js in order to resize the images - unless you go the background image route.

This is pretty much the same as the above but instead of absolutely positioning the images, you use a background image and cover (this will mean you have to choose an aspect ratio and all the mages will be the same size - may look better this way)

```css
.pannel {
  display: inline-block;
}

.pannel > a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center center;
  background-size: cover;

  padding-top:66.6666%; /* for simplicity I have chose the same aspect ratio as above */
}

.image > img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0; 
  right:0;
  top:0; 
  max-width:100%;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="pannel">
  <a href="someref1">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="image"style="background-image:url(http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg);"></div>
      <div>Some text</div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="someref2">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="image"style="background-image:url(https://camo.mybb.com/e01de90be6012adc1b1701dba899491a9348ae79/687474703a2f2f7777772e6a71756572797363726970742e6e65742f696d616765732f53696d706c6573742d526573706f6e736976652d6a51756572792d496d6167652d4c69676874626f782d506c7567696e2d73696d706c652d6c69676874626f782e6a7067);"></div>
      <div>Some text2</div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="someref3">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="image"style="background-image:url(http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg);"></div>
      <div>Text with a maximum width</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

You will notice that in the above snippet, the second image looks like the other 2, even though it has a different aspect ratio to them

Comment: Ty, this works pretty good. What is needed in JS for this? I mean, im the super noob web developer(actually it's my first htlm page). And what kind of troubles usage of JS may cause?

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure you want to put image as whole content or not , if you want then use this code

```
<style>
.pannel {
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
    border: #88F 4px solid;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgb(240, 240, 255);
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-size: 150%;
}

.pannel > a > div {
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: #AAF 1px solid;
    margin: 0 auto 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 9px;
    margin: 3px;
}

.pannel > a > div img {
    width: 100%;

}
</style>
```

and html code

```
<div class="pannel">
<a href="someref1">
    <div>
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg">

        <div>Some text</div>
    </div>
</a>
<a href="someref2">
    <div>
        <img
            src="https://camo.mybb.com/e01de90be6012adc1b1701dba899491a9348ae79/687474703a2f2f7777772e6a71756572797363726970742e6e65742f696d616765732f53696d706c6573742d526573706f6e736976652d6a51756572792d496d6167652d4c69676874626f782d506c7567696e2d73696d706c652d6c69676874626f782e6a7067">

        <div>Some text2</div>
    </div>
</a>
<a href="someref3">
    <div>
        <img
            src="http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg">

        <div>Text with a maximum width</div>
    </div>
</a>
</div>
```